# Use cv2.VideoWriter with ImageGrab.grab to have full screen record

Tags: python-imaging-library, opencv, python

Please see the part of codes below, how can I do in videowriter and imagegrab command, to have full screen record always whatever I use another PC/Monitor.

```
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
    vid=cv2.VideoWriter(r"C:\\IQOutput\\123.avi", fourcc, 12, (1280,720) )
    while(True):
        img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0,0,1280,720))
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer my own question, use tkinter winfo to get screen size and then put them in to videowriter and imagegrab:

```
import tkinter as tk
window = tk.Tk()

width = window.winfo_screenwidth()
height = window.winfo_screenheight()
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
vid=cv2.VideoWriter(r"C:\\IQOutput\\123.avi", fourcc, 12, (width, height))
while(True):
    img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0,0,width,height))
```

Comment: You did `while(True)` for capturing, but you never write anything into the _vid_ variable...